# Django templates, how to make a list of item's values from list of items

Tags: django, django-templates

I have list of items:

`items = [item1, item2, ...]`
 where

`item1 = {'name': 'item1', 'value': 1}` and so on.

In templates i have a list of these items: `{{ items }}`

How can i get a list [item1.name, item2.name, ...] in templates?

Comment: Do you perhaps want a `for` loop?

Comment: I had a believe that there is a more delicate way than a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, just add [`.values_list('name', flat=True)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) to your queryset. Now you are passing a list of item names to your template.

Other options:

- Use a for loop to iterate over items.
- Make a custom template tag.

Comment: unfortunately, i can't change the view. There are uses of other item's attributes in templates. But seems i jsut got to make another context variable with .value_lsit, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your just want to iterate the names in items:

```
{% for item in items %}
<p>name: {{item.name}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the `items` like that, in a `for`:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <p>Name: {{ item.name }}</p>
    <p>Value: {{ item.value }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

You can't "create" variables in the Django Template Engine, but you can do it in your View:
`items_names = [x['name'] for x in items]`

And then access the `items_names` in your template.